# Separating Image link in Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula, identity-column

I'm looking for a quick way to separate image links in Excel, either by formula or standard means.

Here is an example:

> http://www.diamondtraces.com/ebay/items/Diamond-Traces_Solitaire-Pendant_PD875-PD880_1.jpg,http://www.diamondtraces.com/ebay/items/Diamond-Traces_Solitaire-Pendant_PD875-PD880_2.jpg,http://www.diamondtraces.com/ebay/items/Diamond-Traces_Authenticity_Card_Round.jpg,http://www.diamondtraces.com/ebay/items/Diamond-Traces_Loose_Round.jpg,http://www.diamondtraces.com/ebay/items/Diamond-Traces_AGI_Certificate_Round.jpg,http://www.diamondtraces.com/ebay/items/Diamond-Traces_Wooden_Jewelry_Box.jpg

Each link has to be separate in each row.  Take into consideration that I have thousands of these products that must be uploaded with different images ![enter image description here][1]. Also I have provided an image reference to better assist.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Find/Replace function in MS Word:

1. Copy/Paste your links in MS Word.
2. Use a Find/Replace, with Find of `,` and replace of `^p` (this means a newline in MS Word when you use the 'Use Wildcard' mode):

[image]

Then you can copy/paste them back to Excel if you need those links there.